# How can I test the session variables in Grails?

Tags: grails, testing

I have two issues with testing a Grails controller.

I have a controller contains some methods like this one:

```
def save() {
    def x =session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT.authentication.principal.id
    def user = User.get(x)
}
```

and to test this I wrote the test method like this:

```
def testSave () {
    myCont.save()
}
```

And when I run this, I see a WARN from the database while getting the user which is:

```
[main] WARN core.DatastoreUtils - Cannot unbind session, there's no SessionHolder registered
```

So, my questions are:

- How to inject or init the session while testing so I can get this user from session?
- How can I remove the WARN message?

Comment: Are you trying to unit test it? Which version of Grails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to unit test it and would just like to stub it out (and aren't using anything with more sophisticated mocking/stubbing) you could do it quick and easy with a map. Put `@TestFor(YourControllerClass)` right above your test class declaration. Then you can do something like:

```
controller.session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT = [authentication:[principal:[id: 'blah']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do an Integration test and set the session yourself as shown [here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/webtest/tests/MiscSpec.groovy).

Answer (score 0):

## Have u tried this one ?

```
import grails.test.*
class UserControllerTests extends ControllerUnitTestCase {
    void testIndex() {
      controller.index()
      assertEquals controller.list, controller.redirectArgs["action"]
    }
}
```

## assuming this controller to test

```
def index = {
  if(session?.user?.role == "admin"){
    redirect(action:list,params:params)
  }else{
    flash.message = "Sorry, you are not authorized to view this list."
    redirect(controller:"home", action:index)
  }
```

## Testing

Testing for session and flash values

```
void testIndex() {
  def jdoe = new User(name:"John Doe", role:"user")
  def suziq = new User(name:"Suzi Q", role:"admin")

  controller.session.user = jdoe
  controller.index()
  assertEquals "home", controller.redirectArgs["controller"]
  assertTrue controller.flash.message.startsWith("Sorry")

  controller.session.user = suziq
  controller.index()
  assertEquals controller.list, controller.redirectArgs["action"]
}
```

for detailed reference [1]: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails10209/